# Svelte Components: IntrinsicElements or SvelteHTMLElements for extending with HTML types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, svelte

I'm looking to extend my components with the base svelte html types to improve the extensibility and reusability of my components. I have managed to find two ways of achieving this with props exported from the script of the component.

Option 1

```
export let restProps: svelteHTML.IntrinsicElements['div'] | undefined = undefined;
```

Option 2

```
export let restProps: SvelteHTMLElements['div'] | undefined = undefined;
```

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve

```
// /+page.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  import {MyComponent} from './MyComponent.svelte';
</script>
<MyComponent restProps={{
  class:"some-class",
  "aria-label": "some label",
  "on:mousedown": (e) => console.log(e),
  role: 'button'
}} />
```

```
// /MyComponent.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  export let restProps: svelteHTML.IntrinsicElements['button'] | undefined = undefined;
  // OR export let restProps: SvelteHTMLElements['button'] | undefined = undefined;
</script>
<button {...restProps} />
```

Which type definition should I be using and why?

I tried both approaches and they both work as far as I know. I just want to know if one is better/preferred over the other?

Answer (score 1):

Both are not the intended way, as far as I know.

Bundling everything into one property is not necessary, given the built-in `$$restProps`. The properties overall can be typed via `$$Props` which can be defined as an `interface`/`type` that uses an attributes interface from `'svelte/elements'`.

E.g. with a button:

```js
import type { HTMLButtonAttributes } from 'svelte/elements';

interface $$Props extends HTMLButtonAttributes {
  // explicitly defined props here
}
```

Unfortunately explicitly defined props that are already typed in their `export let ...` statement currently have to be repeated.

[Relevant issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/442)

Comment: $$props and $$restProps are not recommended. the following is directly from the Svelte docs:

$$props references all props that are passed to a component, including ones that are not declared with export. It is not generally recommended, as it is difficult for Svelte to optimise. But it can be useful in rare cases – for example, when you don't know at compile time what props might be passed to a component.

Comment: $$restProps contains only the props which are not declared with export. It can be used to pass down other unknown attributes to an element in a component. It shares the same optimisation problems as $$props, and is likewise not recommended.

Comment: This is exactly that "rare case".